# C++ Compiler ignoring class specialization with templatized type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a helper class used to provide partially specialized versions of methods to another class.  I have the primary template and two specializations:

```
template<typename BASE, typename ACCESS_METHOD, int MODULE>
struct BaseHelper
{
    void f1()
    {
      ....
    }
 }

template<typename BASE, int MODULE>
template<typename DEVICE>
struct BaseHelper< BASE, StrangeAccessMethod< DEVICE >, MODULE >
{
    void f1()
    {
      ....
    }
 }

template<typename BASE, int MODULE>
struct BaseHelper< BASE, uint32_t, MODULE >
{
    void f1()
    {
      ....
    }
 }
```

If do the following:

```
FpgaBaseHelper< SomeBaseClass, AccessMethod, 1 > helper1;
FpgaBaseHelper< SomeBaseClass, StrangeAccessMethod<MyDevice>, 2> helper2;
FpgaBaseHelper< SomeBaseClass, uint32_t, 3 > helper3;
```

Then the results are that the primary template is instantiated for helper1 and helper2, with the third instantiating the uint32_t specialization.

I need helper2 to use the StrangeAccessMethod<> specialization.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not understand why helper1 and helper3 should select different specs. Are you sure? What is `AccessMethod`?

Comment: The last one should be:  FpgaBaseHelper< SomeBaseClass, uint32_t, 3 > helper3;

Comment: You should not use all caps as template parameters. They are reserved for macros.

Comment: Who reserved them? Is this 11th commandment?

Comment: They are reserved by convention. Ignore it if you wish to get a million incredibly confusing compiler errors when you include perfectly good arbitrary headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation:

```
template<typename BASE, int MODULE>
template<typename DEVICE>
struct BaseHelper< BASE, StrangeAccessMethod< DEVICE >, MODULE >
{
}
```

is not correct. It refers to a nested template that is not defined in your primary template. Most likely compiler is not saying anything like in many other cases with templates.

Multiple template headers can be used only in the following case:

```
template<typename BASE, int MODULE> struct BaseHelper
{
  template<typename DEVICE> struct InnerTemplate;   // This is forward declaration.
}

template<typename BASE, int MODULE>
template<typename DEVICE>
struct BaseHelper<BASE, MODULE>::InnerTemplate
{
    // Definition.
}
```

You can try:

```
template<typename BASE, int MODULE, typename DEVICE>
struct BaseHelper< BASE, StrangeAccessMethod< DEVICE >, MODULE >
{
}
```

Maybe it will work.

Comment: I thought parameterized templates were legal.  StrangeAccessMethod<> is the specialization that I need.  If you replace StrangeAccessMethod<> with uint32_t it works?  May not understand what you mean.

Comment: I found an example on StackOverFlow that is similar that what I'm trying to do:

Comment: Beautiful....well goes to show you I had a fundamental misunderstanding on how this works.  Thank you!